# What are people using instead of IMultiValueConverters in Windows 8?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-8

I'm porting an existing WPF application to a Windows 8 application.

In the WPF application we make considerable use of MultiValue convertors to allow us to create values that are combinations of UI element properties and viewmodel properties (the weight of a hippo object and the actualWidth of an itemscontrol) to achieve nice UI effects.

Windows 8, however, doesn't have a MultiValue convertor.

Since I'm porting an application I don't really want to  significantly change my viewmodels or Xaml.

How can I replicate Multivalue controller functionality with a minimum amount of pain and rewriting?

Comment: `I'm porting an existing WPF application to a Windows 8 application.` - I really feel sorry for you. As of now, the WinRT XAML feature set is even inferior to the Silverlight one. That means it is only a small fraction of the full WPF feature set. This means you will have to resort to all sorts of horrible hacks to get this working.

Comment: WinRT is the new CompactFramework, it has everything except........everything

Comment: I use swear words instead. Lots of them :-)

Comment: As a some kind of workaround you could consider using approach described in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229214/multivalue-converter-in-windows-phone

Comment: @Sevenate That looks useful, thank you.  I'll give it a try if I'm ever back in WinRT land.

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to expose a static singleton instance of the VM; for example:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static MainViewModel _mvm;
    public static MainViewModel MVM
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mvm == null)
                _mvm = new MainViewModel();

            return _mvm;
        }
    }
```

Then simple pass the whole VM through:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding MVM}">Run Command</Button>
```

It's not multibinding, but it does allow you to pass multiple parameters.

Comment: The problem isn't on how to pass a viewmodel to a converter.  It's passing viewmodel AND view properties to the converter. (Oh, and you don't appear to be using a converter at all, which is confusing as the question is about converters).

Comment: The answer is that WinRT doesn't support it.  I just thought I'd offer an alternate approach.