# Multivalue converter in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone application.

Lets's say I have a CustomersViewModel class that exposes the list of customers. I have a list in xaml that binds to that list:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource userIdToNameConverter}" />                    
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

So each item in the list box will bind to a single customer object.

CustomersViewModel has an additional property

```
string StoreId
```

In my XAML from above, I would like to pass the StoreId to the converter, in addition to the customer object that I am already passing. How can this be done elegantly?

It seems IMultiValueConverter does not exist on WP8, and it is not possible to do data binding to ConverterParameter of the converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/03/11/tips-winrt-converter-parameter-binding.aspx) explains a work around for the problem. The idea is to create a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your converter. You can then bind your `StoreId` to this, instead of using the `ConverterParameter`.

So on your `UserIdToNameConverter`, you need to inherit from `DependencyObject`, and add the dependency property:

```
public class UserIdToNameConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public string StoreId
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(StoreIdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StoreIdProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StoreIdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StoreId",
                                    typeof (string),
                                    typeof (UserIdToNameConverter),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //Your current code
        //Can now use StoreId instead of ConverterParameter
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //Same as above;
    }
}
```

You can then bind to this dependency property within your view's resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <UserIdToNameConverter x:Key="UserIdToNameConverter" StoreId="{Binding StoreId}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This is assuming your view's `DataContext` is set to the `CustomersViewModel` where it can find the `StoreId` property. You can then use the converter the same way as you have in your question.

As a side note, it won't work if you create the converter within the `ItemTemplate` instead of inside the `Resources`. See the blog post for more information. All credit goes to the blog's author, Sebastien Pertus.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the problem with this approach seems to be you can only really pass additional parameters defined on the page. So I can't pass multiple values to the item bound in an LLS or Listbox.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. You could add another dependency property on the converter if you wanted to bind something else if you need to pass more than one parameter. Or do you mean binding the converter parameter from items in your ListBox? As yes, this isn't that helpful here because the converter needs to be declared outside the ItemTempalte of your ListBox.

Comment: Yup, it was the item in the list box I was referring to, for exactly the same reason you described.